# What is the difference between unmet and incorrect peer dependency?

Tags: npm, yarnpkg

I believe I understand what "unmet peer dependency" means. For example "package-a" depends on "package-b@^2.1.5" but no version of package-b@2.x.x (>=2.1.5) is installed.

But "incorrect dependency" baffles me. It would make no sense to say "package-a is asking for an incorrect dependency". Is it saying that the dependency listed in package-lock.json or yarn.lock doesn't match what package-a says it needs? If this is correct, then how would this be resolved?

When I search for specific discussion about "incorrect dependency" on Github, it seems to show up on issues in the yarn or npm repos. And the resolution usually seems to be a fix to yarn or npm. Is this message for bugs in yarn/npm?

If I search https://docs.npmjs.com/ for "incorrect peer dependency", I get no results.

Comment: Hi John. Sorry that nobody was able to help you here – did you figure it out finally? It would be great to have your package.json and the concrete failing dependencies in your question to help answer. Otherwise this question will not help anybody.

Comment: @Andy. Thanks for responding. I no longer have a project that is giving me that error. But in general it would be helpful to know when is it even possible to get "incorrect peer dependency". Does it only occur when there is a bug in the npm/yarn source code?

Comment: I'm not aware of ever having gotten that message, and as you state it's not in the docs. So I'm afraid I cannot help you further, I don't know where to start w/o concrete examples.

Answer (score 4):

- *Unmet peer dependency* means the dependency has not been installed at all.
- *Incorrect peer dependency* means it has been installed, but in the wrong version.

Given these package.json

```
{
  name: "app"
  dependencies: {
    "package-a": "*"
  }
}

{
  name: "package-a",
  peerDependencies: {
    "package-b": "^2.1.5"
  }
}
```

A `yarn install` will give you an *unmet peer dependency*, since app does not make sure `package-b` gets installed.

If you add it as a dependency, but in a wrong version

```
{
  name: "app"
  dependencies: {
    "package-a": "*",
    "package-b": "~2.0.0"
  }
}
```

you will get an *incorrect peer dependency*.

Comment: That makes sense what you say. But since, like I said in the comments above, I don't have a current project giving that error. So I can't verify your answer and mark it as the correct one. Do you know of an existing npm package and its dependency that this can be verified against?

Comment: You can simply copy an paste my package.jsons here and give it a spin.

Answer (score 0):

I have a current example. In order to meet some unmet peer dependencies I added `vite@>2.0.0-0` to my package.json. This actually installed vite 4.5.0. I have another dependency `@intlify/vite-plugin-vue-i18n` which (in its current installed version 3.4.0) declares a peerDependency on `"vite": "^2.0.0"`. This gets me:

`warning " > @intlify/vite-plugin-vue-i18n@3.4.0" has incorrect peer dependency "vite@^2.0.0".`

Now to go see if there is a newer version of the plugin with a newer dependency.